# Django Model Design for "Wall"-type app

Tags: django, django-models

I am messing about with Django trying to learn more and I'm hitting a bit of a roadblock with understanding of the model design.  I'm attempting to create an app that is like the facebook "wall" but it's purely albums with photos and videos, with comments and votes.  My struggle is understanding how to design the relationship for items that could have many relationships.  As an example, you can upvote photos, videos, comments, albums, and whatever else.  What is the appropriate model design to address non-specific items?  Here is my proposed structure thus far.

```
Album  --primary
--id
--datetime
--created by
--title
--photo(s)
--comment(s)
--+1(s)

photo
--id
--foreignkey album
--datetime
--uploaded by
--caption
--comment(s)
--path
--+1(s)

video
--id
--foreignkey album
--datetime
--caption
--comment(s)
--path
--+1(s)

comments
--id
--user
--datetime
+1(s)


+1s
--id
--user
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a GenericForeignKey:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/contenttypes/

The ContentType model allows you to make

It'd look something like this

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class Upvote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for GenericForeignKey, [example](https://hashedin.com/2017/06/02/django-models-designing-data-model-for-discussion-forum-charcha/):

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "votes"
        index_together = [
            ["content_type", "object_id"],
        ]

    # The following 3 fields represent the Comment or Post
    # on which a vote has been cast
    # See Generic Relations in Django's documentation
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    voter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    type_of_vote = models.IntegerField(choices = (
            (UPVOTE, 'Upvote'),
            (DOWNVOTE, 'Downvote'),
            (FLAG, 'Flag'),
        ))
    submission_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Here, ContentType model represent and store information about the models installed in your project (Album,Photo,Video...), and new instances of ContentType are automatically created whenever new models are installed.

Now we do not need to keep Foreign Key to other Django models we want to track. Using the GenericRelations, we can now track those votes to any model we want without having to modify the Vote model.

The reverse relation will be the part of the models we need to track. For example:

```
class Post:
    ...
    ...
    votes = GenericRelation(Vote) 
    ...
    ...

class Comment:
    ...
    ...
    votes = GenericRelation(Vote) 
    ...
    ...
```

Now, If we put a little thought to our existing Post and Comment models, we would observe that the two models should behave more or less in the same fashion. For instance, both of them can be upvoted, downvoted, flagged, unflagged and so they should provide interfaces to do so.

Hence we can create a base class for them as Votable and push the common behaviours and attributes to it. The Post and Comment will then be concrete classes and will inherit from Votable.

```
class Votable(models.Model):
    """ An object on which people would want to vote
        Post and Comment are concrete classes
    """
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    votes = GenericRelation(Vote)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    # denormalization to save database queries
    # flags = count of votes of type "Flag"
    upvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    downvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    flags = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def upvote(self, user):
        ....
        ....

    def downvote(self, user):
        ....
        ....

class Post(Votable):
    # post specific implementation
    ...
    ...

class Comment(Votable):
    # comment specific implementation
    ...
    ...
```

[Source](https://hashedin.com/2017/06/02/django-models-designing-data-model-for-discussion-forum-charcha/)

[more info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations)

Comment: A lot of good info and reference here.  What if I something needs to be subclassed twice?  Like, a photo can be commentable and votable?

Comment: You can have abstract classes like the above, for example: VotableMixin, CommentableMixin. Then: class Photo(VotableMixin, CommentableMixin)

Comment: `class PostMixin(models.Model):
    vote = models.ForeignKey(Vote)
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comments)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Story(models.Model, PostMixin):
    posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    text = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["posted"]
        verbose_name_plural = "stories"`

Comment: class Story, should only inherit from PostMixin which already inhirits from models.Model

Comment: I'm sure there are a lot of resources out there. But a good book like "Two Scoops of Django" advises to avoid GenericRelations and instead, use ForeignKey and ManyToMany.

Comment: @ziiro that's the route I expected I would have to take.  I should have emphasized the intention of using the word _many_ better.